# Which CertificateSigningRequest to use

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Should the iOS **Production app signing Certificate** and iOS **Production Push Certificate** use the same CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest for push notifications to go through?

Will changing the certSigningRequest and using a new certificate still send push to my old apps.

Answer (score 1):

You may use same **CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest** for iOS Production app signing certificate and iOS Production Push Certificate. But as standard practice says, you should create different **CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest** for for different certificates.